# Facebook Graph API - Page - Scheduled posts not coming back in promotable posts call

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, posts

I'm trying to list all future scheduled posts for a business page but when I request promotable posts as per the documentation graph.facebook.com//promotable_posts its not pulling back unscheduled posts with one exception - directly after I initially create a new scheduled post.

I can't figure out why but this is the only time it will pull back the list and it will only do it for the first request after a new post not subsequent.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you definitely using the page access token? all unpublished and scheduled posts should be on that endpoint when requested on behalf of the page

Comment: Thank Igy, I just checked and you're right, it wasn't setting the access token correctly.