# View Scheduled Posts via Facebook API

Tags: facebook, api

How can you view scheduled posts via the Facebook API.

I have tried:

https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_URL/promotable_posts?access_token=XXXX

But all I get returned is posts that are already published, no future (scheduled) posts are displayed anywhere.

I have also played with 'since' and 'until' variable timestamps trying to capture the future posts but with no luck.

The access token I am using is from the app that has full access to the page and can read/write posts to the /feed

Related post: [Facebook Graph API - Page - Scheduled posts not coming back in promotable posts call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19171051/facebook-graph-api-page-scheduled-posts-not-coming-back-in-promotable-posts)

This is driving me a bit nuts. I hope someone can help?

Thanks,

Comment: Anybody? Would seem total sense to me to have an end point as:  https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_URL/scheduled_posts Instead of the ambiguous /promotable_posts but doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

Ok finally figured this out :)

You need to add the **is_published=false** to the call.

https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_URL/promotable_posts?is_published=false&access_token=XXXX